# Problems with calculating total interest in a loan calculator program (C++)

Tags: c++

I've been developing a simple loan calculator program for my c++ class, and I cannot for the life of me figure out where i'm going wrong. The whole program works as intended except for how the total interest for the loan is calculated. I feel like the answer here is simple, but I cannot see it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numberOfPayments;
        double monthlyInterestRate;
        double Loan;
        double monthlyPayment;
        double annualInterestRate;
        double interestTotal;
        double loanTotal;


    cout << "Enter the loan amount (principal) -->  ";
    cin >> Loan;
    cout << "Enter the YEARLY interest rate as a percentage -->  ";
    cin  >> annualInterestRate;
    cout << "Enter the number of payments -->  ";
    cin >> numberOfPayments;

    monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12;
    monthlyInterestRate = monthlyInterestRate / 100;
    monthlyPayment = (monthlyInterestRate)  *   pow((1 + monthlyInterestRate), numberOfPayments) /  (pow((1 + monthlyInterestRate), numberOfPayments) - 1) * Loan; // Amount of monthly payments
    loanTotal = (monthlyPayment * numberOfPayments); // Total amount due for loan
    interestTotal = monthlyInterestRate * numberOfPayments  * monthlyPayment; 


    cout << monthlyInterestRate << endl;
    cout << "Loan Amount:                                    $" << setw(8) << Loan << endl;
    cout << "Yearly Interest Rate:                            " << setw(8) << annualInterestRate << "%" << endl;           
    cout << "Number of Payments:                              " << setw(8) << numberOfPayments << endl;
    cout << "Monthly Payment:                                $" << setw(8) << setprecision(5) << monthlyPayment << endl;
    cout << "Amount Paid Back:                               $" << setw(8) << setprecision(7) << loanTotal << endl;
    cout << "Interest Paid:                                  $" << setw(8) << setprecision(5) << interestTotal  << endl;
    cout << "\n\nProgram Over";
    cout << "\n\n\nPress Enter to end -->";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First error right there: `monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12;`  How are you compounding?  What type of "annual" interest is it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your questions. It is supposed to use simple interest, if that helps.

Comment: What is it printing and what are you expecting it to print? The calculation of the monthly payment at least looks right to me.

Comment: Are you expecting to use APR or EAR as your annual interest rate input?  If you are trying to compare the annual interest (APR) with the sum of the monthly interest, you are going to be slightly off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a math and programming problem.

The interest calculation is wrong as pointed out by @m24p and should be improved
as

```
interestTotal = (numberOfPayments * monthlyPayment) - Loan; // (@dvnrrs)
```

But programs should follow financial calculations to the penny. (Or whatever unit of currency).  The initial calculation of monthly payment needs to be rounded.  Monthly interest, payments and balances all need rounding.  Then end result is usually a few cents different than full `double` math.  Ideally this would be done in the lowest unit of currency to avoid the repetitive *100 and /100.

With $100,000 6% and 360 monthly payments, came up with a $0.26 more total interest.
The last payment, month 361, was for $0.45.

```
  monthlyPayment = round(monthlyPayment * 100)/100;
  double RealInterestTotal = 0.0;
  unsigned Month = 0;
  while (Loan > 0.0){
    Month++;
    double InterstThisMonth = round(Loan*monthlyInterestRate*100)/100;
    RealInterestTotal = R(RealInterestTotal + InterstThisMonth);
    double PaymentOnLoan = R(monthlyPayment - InterstThisMonth);
    if (PaymentOnLoan > Loan) {
      PaymentOnLoan = Loan;
    }
    Loan = R(Loan - PaymentOnLoan);
  }
  cout << "Real Interest Paid:                             $" << setw(8)
          << setprecision(8) << RealInterestTotal << endl;
  cout << "Months:                                          " << setw(8)
          << setprecision(8) << Month << endl;
```

---

To address a good point raised by @Zac Howland, the use of `round()` above does not show clearly the 2 conditions where I suggest rounding should occur:
1) a calculation has a fractional cent as in `monthlyPayment` and `InterstThisMonth` and
2) rounding is use due to the typical binary64 nature of a `double` representing dollars rather than cents.  Re-wrote to to use a function `R()` which would be a no-op if calculations were done in cents.

For fun see [Vancouver Stock Exchange](http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/users/vuik/wi211/disasters.html#stock)

Comment: I can tell you from personal experience, financial institutions do not round intermediate results to 2 digits.  Most go to at least 4 digits and only round the final result.  So holding the doubles until the output is fine, and actually encouraged to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: @Zac Howland Interesting - my personal experience differs.  The issue is often what is an intermediate result?  The monthly payment is typically a contractual amount and thus cannot have a fractional cent value.   The monthly interest accumulated directly affects the monthly balance.  Neither of these I would call intermediate results as one may payoff the loan at that point.  In any case, I'd suggest we agree that financial programming have internal and legal requirements that involve rounding.  Programmers need to be aware they exist and code accordingly.

Comment: I agree with the last point.  But just to share my experience (both from a bank perspective, and from a a gas station accounting perspective) - an intermediate value is anything that is not the final amount.  So the monthly payment amount is an intermediate value - when printed on an invoice, it would be rounded to the nearest penny, but when used in calculations, would be stored with high precision (usually 4 decimal places).  The same is true for gasoline:  You buy gas at a price of X.YZ99 per gallon (in the US).  This is done to prevent rounding errors when dealing with partial gallons.

Comment: @Zac Howland If the monthly interest was rounded for display, but still held to finer precision internally, that would result in the remaining balance also having the same rounded display but different and finer internal value.  Eventually a month would occur where the before/after balance, accumulated interest and monthly payment do not add up in their display form.  Is this what you suggest banks allow?

Comment: Not just allow - but require in most cases.  But to clarify, the monthly interest isn't rounded; the monthly payment amount on the invoice would be.  The extra amount would go to principle, which would just lower your bill (a fraction of a penny) next month.

Comment: @Zac Howland  Although I think our views are rounding closer to each other - looks like we still differ a bit.  I've updated to be more clear on where I am rounding a value like 1234.567 into 1234.57 versus doing a round so 123.999999999 is 124.0.  This second type of round would not be needed if values were whole number of cents.

Answer (score 1):

```
interestTotal = monthlyInterestRate * numberOfPayments  * monthlyPayment;
```

This should be

```
interestTotal = (numberOfPayments * monthlyPayment) - Loan;
```

`numberOfPayments * monthlyPayment` gives you the total amount you **actually** paid.  You just need to subtract the amount you borrowed (`Loan`) to figure out what portion of that was interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
interestTotal = monthlyInterestRate * numberOfPayments  * monthlyPayment;
```

This is not correct.  The total interest doesn't need to be multiplied by the monthlyPayment.  You'll need a different calculation.

It's not really a C++ question, is it?

Comment: When I delete that part of the calculation, it still does not give me a correct output.

Comment: Thanks, dvnrrs.
@user3281514 - Sure, you still need to do the correct calculation.  Let us know if you have any specific questions you need help with on it.

Comment: I suppose it's not a C++ question, since moreover what I need is how to correctly calculate the total interest. I apologize for my naivete.

Comment: No problem.

So, the interest charged any given month is going to be the interest rate times the current loan amount, right?  Do you follow me?  You might be expected to use loops.
...let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Total interest is the total amount paid (monthly payment times number of payments) minus the principal: `interestTotal = (numberOfPayments * monthlyPayment) - Loan`

Comment: Well, assuming the principle is reduced to zero by that time.  I don't think it's guaranteed to be.

Comment: Since "number of payments" is not calculated, but entered.

Comment: In my calculation, that equation negates, as loanTotal = (numberOfPayments * monthlyPayment).

Comment: @m24p I don't understand (my wife has the finance degree, not me), but it seems to me if the principal isn't reduced to zero after all the payments are made, then you didn't calculate the monthly payment correctly, right?

Comment: Oh, right.  I didn't see that monthly payment was calculated by the program.